# Apparent size of and object

Tags: optics, geometry

How can i prove that the apparent size of an object Is inversely proportional to the distance from the observer?

Comment: You do it with a *geometrical construction* using a compass, straightedge, and the laws of triangles. can you show us your work so far, and tell us where exactly you are stuck? -NN

Answer (score 2):

By "apparent size" what we mean is the angle the object makes from your point of view. This angle can be computed by basic geometric arguments.
[image: Apparent angle geometric computation]
where $L$ is the size of the object and $d$ is your distance from the object.

Using the above geometric construction, we find with basic trigonometry
$$ \alpha = 2 \arctan \left(\frac{L}{2d}\right) \approx \frac{L}{d} $$
when the object is far away, $d \gg L$.